# Why would the last sector be unused?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sectors

I was bored and decided to open up my hard drive in HxD (a free hex editor) and wanted to see what the REAL size of my disk is. So I did and scrolled to the bottom and discovered that the last sector is unused and unwritten to. Why would this be?

[image: screenshot]

(Also it says it isn't the last sector, but it is)

Comment: How did you established it was unused?

Comment: I've had this disk for 6 years and it's still empty. Also, it looks like this on my other **drives**

Comment: It's for the 6800 hcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last sector would be unused if 1) it was not included in any partition, or 2) if it is
inside a partition, but the partition does not carry a filesystem, or 3) if it is in a
filesystem, it has not been allocated to any file, or 4)if it has been assigned to a file,
the file does not have anything to put in there. You give absolutely no information to
decide the state of the sector you show. There is no reason to think that sector is unused,
the fact that it is all nulls indicates nothing.